# Cumulative approach for finding longest common prefix using C not working

Tags: arrays, c, append, accumulate, strncpy

I am attempting to take code that I have written in C++ for some basic problems, then re-writing in other languages as a way to become more familiar with syntax and library functions in these other languages.

I am currently working on a problem from leetcode, I know I can find solutions to the problem, but would like to come up with my own working solution before doing so.

This basic problem is to just find the longest prefix amongst an array of strings. Like I said, I am using my C++ working solution and trying to translate to another language. In this case I am attempting to translate the solution to C.

I am using a basic accumulator method. However, unlike my C++ version which worked, the version in C is returning the entire first work, instead of the prefix. For instance if the array is ["run", "rude", "running"], then it should return "ru", but instead it returns "run".

I am thinking this is something to do with the way I am copying, appending, or assigning values, but at the moment, I cannot see where the problem is.

Any thoughts and help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
// Variables
char * longestCommonPrefix(char ** strs, int strsSize){
char *result = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
char current = ' ';

// Find smallest word 
int smallestWordSize = 201;
int size = sizeof(strs) / sizeof *strs;
for (int index = 0; index < size; ++index) {
        if (strlen(strs[index]) < smallestWordSize) {
            smallestWordSize = strlen(strs[index]);
        }
    }  

// For case where there is only one element
if(size == 1){
    result = strs[0];
}

// Create result string
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < smallestWordSize; ++i) {
     strncpy(current, strs[0][i], 1);
        for (int j = 1; j < size; ++j) {
            if (current != strs[j][i]) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        strncat(result, current, 1);
                  
        }
    }


return result;
```

}

Yes, I realize I am not using the parameter strsSize, as in the C++ solution, it didn't have that parameter, and I am attempting to do as much of a straight translation from one language to the other.

Comment: The best advice you can get regardless of language is to learn to debug effectively. Run your program in in a debugger and trace it as it runs to find out where it starts to go wrong. [How to debug small small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What is `strncopy`? If you still need further help after debugging please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're only allocating enough space to hold a single char for your result pointer...

Comment: This is the complete code. I just plug it into leetcode, there is no driver or main. It is just a function.  Yes, I noticed the spelling error, fixed it, still doesn't work.

Comment: Advice: Don't learn just on leetcode alone. Build and debug it locally. As it is, you don't have the tools to debug as soon as something goes wrong. In "real life" the debugging step is as important (if not more) as writing the code itself.

Comment: Thank you. I do code outside of leetcode, then just copy my code into leetcode. I also just use leetcode for coding problems. I have many resources I use for learning. I know how to debug to an extent. I was just hoping that my problem is so simple that someone could spot it and let me know.

Comment: @Shawn, how would I add more space for my result pointer? Should it be something like char *result = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)) *201 ?

Comment: terrylt1, `char ** strs ... int size = sizeof(strs) / sizeof *strs;` is 1.  Size of of a pointer divided by the size of a pointer.  Surely you do not want this.

Comment: Either allocate enough space for the largest possible result string to start, or grow as needed with `realloc()` (Basically, having to do explicitly what C++ things like `std::string` do for you.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no that is not what I wanted. Thank you for pointing that out. what I am attempting to do in that piece of code is to determine the number of elements in the array. Any thoughts on how I could do that?

Comment: Ok, so based on the comments, I believe, at least part, if not all of my problem is the fact that in my code, the program thinks there is only one element in the array, when in my example there are three elements. How can I determine the number of elements in an array in C. I know how to do this in other languages but not in C.

Comment: You have to keep track of the size yourself and pass it as an extra argument to functions that work on the array. Or use a special value to mark the end of the array, like the nul character in strings.

Comment: terrylt1 Pass into `longestCommonPrefix()` the array count like `longestCommonPrefix(array_count, pointer_to_first_element_of_the_array)`.  For more info, post a [mcve].

Comment: `result = strs[0];` would result in a memory leak, and probably UD when you try to free your string one time to many.

Comment: What you should do is: 1. calculate length of common prefix. 2. `malloc` enough space for your result string (+ zero termination) 3. copy prefix with `memcpy`. 4. add zero termination.

Comment: Oh, and always compile with `-Wall`. There are some compiler warnings you should *really* pay attention to.

Comment: @HAL9000 can you please explain why this would cause a memory leak and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: @terrylt1, How can you `free` the memory allocated with `malloc` if you have no pointers pointing at it? Trying to learn c by translating some code from another language by half-guessing some syntax and common idioms are a bad idea. Get a good C tutorial. There are a lot of bad ones, so this part is maybe the most difficult part of learning C. Then after you have a solid grasp of pointers, arrays and `malloc`/`free`, you could try rewriting things in c. Remember that syntactic differences between c and other languages are mostly trivial, the real differences are how c handles memory.

Answer (score 0):

So, after working on this, I finally came up with a solution. During this process I did discover more simple solutions, but as I said I wanted this to kind of match my accumulator approach I did in C++. This is what I came up, for those who might be interested.

```
char * longestCommonPrefix(char ** strs, int strsSize){
char current = ' ';

int smallestWordSize = 201;
for (int index = 0; index < strsSize; ++index) {
        if (strlen(strs[index]) < smallestWordSize) {
            smallestWordSize = strlen(strs[index]);
        }
    }

    char *result = malloc(sizeof(char) * smallestWordSize +1);
    result[0] = '\0';

    if(strsSize == 0) {
      return result;
    }

     if(strsSize == 1){
           result = strs[0];
           return result;
      }

      int i = 0;
      bool match = true;

      for (i = 0; i < smallestWordSize && match; ++i) {
          current = strs[0][i];

          for (int j = 1; j < strsSize && match; ++j) {
                if (current != strs[j][i]) {
                     i--;
                     match = false;
                }
          }
      }

      if (i > 0){
           strncat(result, strs[0], i);
      }
      else {
           result = "";
           return result;;
      }

 return result;
```

}